# Create Task without lambda

Tags: c#, lambda, async-await

Trying to pass function instead lambda expression and finally mixed up why line:

```
int t2 = await Task.Run( ()=>Allocate2() );
```

not raises error. This lambda expression `()=>Allocate2()` not returns `Task`. Why no error?

How to create task without lambda expression with function `Allocate`?

```
 static async void Example()
    {

        int t = await Task.Run(Allocate);
        int t2 = await Task.Run( ()=>Allocate2() );
        Console.WriteLine("Compute: " + t);
    }


static Task<int> Allocate()
    {
    return 1;
    }


static int Allocate2()
    {
    return 1;
    }
```

Comment: [`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx) return `Task`. What this task is doing inside is another story (see overloads).

Comment: running this I get this error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int>'` because your return type isnt matched.  but what is it that you are trying to acheive.

Comment: I'm trying to run task without using lambda expression

Comment: why don't you make `Allocate` async and call `var t = await Allocate();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Task.Run()` wants you to pass a parameterless `Action` or `Func` to it.

A lambda can be assigned to an `Action` or a `Func` (as appropriate) which is why calling `Task.Run()` with a lambda works for you.

If you don't want to use a lambda, you must explicitly create an `Action` or a `Func`, passing the method you want to call to the constructor of the `Action` or the `Func`.

The following demonstrates:

```
static void Main()
{
    var task = Task.Run(new Action(MyMethod));
}

static void MyMethod()
{
    Console.WriteLine("MyMethod()");
}
```

OR:

```
static void Main()
{
    var task = Task.Run(new Func<int>(MyMethod));
}

static int MyMethod()
{
    Console.WriteLine("MyMethod()");
    return 42;
}
```

Note that this doesn't work if the method needs one or more parameters. In that event, you must use a lambda.

Comment: You could also perform an explicit cast as an alternative to `new`ing.

Comment: How to use explicit cast in this case?

Comment: @vico You can cast it like so: `var task = Task.Run((Func<int>)MyMethod);` - but I don't really think that is an improvement. It actually ends up with more or less the same generated code. (See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24705925/cast-to-func-vs-new-func) for more info)

Comment: @Downvoter: If you think this answer is incorrect, you should explain why. If it really is incorrect, people should know - otherwise it will be especially misleading since it is marked as the correct answer.